# Solve set of simple equations given only a few variables

Tags: python, performance, recursion, sympy

I have a set of a few hundred simple sum equations. For example here are 3:

```
 w1 - u1 - u2 = 0 
 w1 + w2 - w3 - u3 = 0
 w1 - w2 - w4 = 0
```

I am trying to find a way to solve as many as possible given only a few of the values. For example, in the above equation set if I have `u1` and `u2` I can calculate `w1`, but nothing else.
Given `u1`, `u2` and `w2` I can calculate `w1` and `w4`. And so forth...

Currently I'm approaching this in a fairly straight forward way (psudo code):

```
while there are new results:
     for each equation:
         try to solve equation:
             if solved update result set
```

This works but feels clunky and inefficient.

Is there a better way? (using Python if that is relevant)

**EDIT:** I know this could be solved as series of linear equations, IF i know enough of the values. I'm looking for a method to use when I don't know enough to solve as a system of linear equations (or possibly there a fancy way to reduce the problem somehow)

**EDIT 2**: erroneous, deleted

**EDIT 3**: For anyone interested in my solution using sympy:

```
from sympy import linsolve, symbols, linear_eq_to_matrix
w1, w2, w3, w4, u1, u2, u3 = symbols("w1, w2, w3, w4, u1, u2, u3", integer=True)
variables = [w1, w2, w3, w4, u1, u2, u3]

def my_solver(known_vals):

    eqns = [w1 - u1 - u2, 
            w1 + w2 - w3 - u3,
            w1 - w2 - w4]

    #add the known variables to equation list
    for x in known_vals.keys():
        eqns.append(x - (known_vals[x]))

    A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(eqns, variables)
    solution = linsolve((A, b), variables)

    return solution


my_solver({w1:2, u2:-2})
```

Comment: Can you post some code with your data structures?  There are many ways to represent these things, and I'd like to be able to answer using your own set-up.

Comment: @Prune - sure thing, I'm away from the office today but will get an example up tonight

Comment: @Prune - added some code based on my example.

Comment: Sounds like you should just throw this into [`sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve) and call it a day. That'll give you a complete basis for the solution set, including the values of any variables whose values can be determined. Your brute-force solution isn't going to find everything.

Comment: @user2357112 - that looks pretty much exactly what I'm after, I'll go read the docs... and thanks for pointing out that my code above is not going to work. I realsie my mistake now.

Comment: @user2357112 - do you want to make this the an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Wouldn't the REEF of the augmented system produce the known solutions in any row with a single coefficient  and give the dependent relationships in all other rows? Any inconsistent equations would filter to the bottom as they would be of the form [0 0 ... 1].

Comment: @Jared Goguen - sorry you'll have to help me out here, what's the REEF? It's one of those hard to google acronyms...

Comment: (Reduced Row Echelon Form) Googling "RREF" should do it for you... if you have no background in linear algebra, then you might have to do a little background reading, but it should be light, most texts that I've seen go over this material is  Chapter 1 or 2.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I meant that you should encode known variable values as equations in the `eqns` list rather than plugging them in with `subs` afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get SymPy and stuff the whole system of linear equations into [`sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve). It'll give you the whole solution space, including the values of variables with determined values, in a form dependent on whether the system has 0, 1, or infinite solutions.

There's probably also a NumPy/SciPy way to get the solution set of an underdetermined system, but whatever that way is, I don't know it. Google suggests a [singular value decomposition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) would be useful, but I haven't figured out how you'd get a basis for the solution set out of that.

---

In case it wasn't clear, "the whole system of linear equations" includes formulating known variable values as equations. For example, if you know that `u2 = 5`, then `u2 = 5` would be one of the linear equations. You'd represent that as `u2 - 5` in the `eqns` list.

Answer (score 2):

Your original description was clear enough, complete with example.

What you want for a *general* solution is a data flow graph and some graph traversal algorithms.  However, with only 200 equations to work through, your brute-force method is going to be effective enough.  However, for long-term use, I'd set it up the way we did in compiler construction:

---

**Data Objects**

**Equation** has a list of variables and coefficients (LHS) and constant (RHS).  Also, keep a count of how many variables are still unsolved.  These variables are references to ...

**Variable** includes a list of equation references (uses) and a value (None if not solved yet).

**Open equation list** is a list of unsolved equations.

---

**Algorithm**

**Initialization**
Sort the equation list by quantity of unknowns -- at least to identify those with only 1 remaining unknown.

**Iteration**

```
while there are equations with only 1 unknown:
    for each such equation:
        solve that equation for the remaining variable
        for each equation in the variable's reference list:
            update that equation
```

Note that "update that equation" can involve several steps.  Most notably, make sure you update the count of unknowns; if that's now 1, move it into the queue to solve.

---

**Afters**

If you're lucky, you'll have solved all the equations ... or you'll have at least as many equations as unknowns, so you can use the linear solving facilities of your favourite math package to finish the job.

Comment: "your brute-force method is going to be effective enough" - eh, that depends on your standard of "effective enough". It isn't guaranteed to find the values of all variables with determined values; it might not even come close.

Comment: Well, that comment was valid when I wrote it -- roughly 6 hours before the edit with the code.

Answer (score -1):

You may use some linear algebra methods to solve the problem.

assume the 4th equation is

```
w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 = 2
```

then you can write the matrix as :

```
In [28]: martix = np.array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0],
...:        [ 1,  1, -1,  0],
...:        [ 1, -1,  0, -1],
...:        [ 1,  1,  1,  1]])
```

assume u1 = 10 ,u2 = -5, u3 = 6, u4 = 2 and move them to right:

```
In [34]: ans = np.array([u1+u2, u3, 0, u4])
```

then use `numpy` to solve:

```
In [35]: np.linalg.solve(martix,ans)
Out[35]: array([  5.,  -7.,  -8.,  12.])
```

you got w1=5 w2=-7 w3=-8 and w4=12

Comment: this is fine if I know all of  u1, u2, u3 and u4. But what if I only know 2 of them?

Comment: @jprockbelly the `u` you have doesn't mean so much, you have to ensure you have same amount of equations and the unknown number. or you can't get the unknown number.

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear, I'm looking for a solution for when I DON'T have the same number of unknowns and equations. In my real world case I have ~200 equations and ~75 variables but I will only know a fraction of the variables at one time. See edit above